# In MATLAB, what ASCII characters are allowed to be in a function name?

Tags: function, matlab, variables, syntax, naming-conventions

I have a set of objects that I read information out of that contain information that ends up becoming a MATLAB m file.  One piece of information ends up being a function name in MATLAB.  I need to remove all of the not-allowed characters from that string before writing the M file out to the filesystem.  Can someone tell me what characters make up the set of allowed characters in a function name for MATLAB?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Legal names follow the pattern [A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]*, i.e. an alphabetic character followed by zero or more alphanumeric-or-underscore characters, up to NAMELENGTHMAX characters.

Since MATLAB variable and function naming rules are the same, you might find [genvarname](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/genvarname.html) useful. It sanitizes arbitrary strings into legal MATLAB names.

Answer (score 5):

**The short answer...**

Any alphanumeric characters or underscores, as long as the name starts with a letter.

**The longer answer...**

The MATLAB documentation has a section "[Working with M-Files](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f7-41453.html)" that discusses naming with a little more detail. Specifically, it points out the functions [NAMELENGTHMAX](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/namelengthmax.html) (the maximum number of characters in the name that the OS will pay attention to), [ISVARNAME](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/isvarname.html) (to check if the variable/function name is valid), and [ISKEYWORD](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/iskeyword.html) (to display restricted keywords).

Answer (score 3):

Edited:

this may be more informative:

http://scv.bu.edu/documentation/tutorials/MATLAB/functions.html

Comment: There are more rules than I realized.